Connectedness of intersections of sets
Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathcal{R}^n$ with nonempty interior. Let $x_0\in \partial K$ (boundary of $K$). I want to show there exists a $\delta$ such that for any $\delta'<\delta$, $B_{\delta'}(x_0)\cap int\{K\}$ is connected. I don't even know if the statement is true. I asked a similar question (here Connectedness of intersection of two sets) but I did not formulate the question well so I am posting as a new question. @ECL said this is equivalent to asking if $K$ is locally connected. If I assume $K$ is locally connected, would the statement be true? If so, how can I make the argument rigorous? If not true, could you please provide a counter example?

I presume that, for you, $\emptyset$ is connected? Because $\operatorname{int}K$ could be empty.

@SassatelliGiulio Thanks for pointing that out. I am assuming $K$ has nonempty interior. I will edit the question.

You can still have instances where $\operatorname{int}(K)\ne\emptyset\land \exists x_0\in\partial K,\exists \delta>0, B_\delta(x_0)\cap \operatorname{int}(K)=\emptyset$, if that is a problem.

@SassatelliGiulio Ok, I see what you mean. I will take empty set as connected.

One problem with your statement is that the point $x_0$ you chose to begin with might be isolated from $\operatorname{int}(K)$; e.g. if $K = [0,1] \cup \{2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 = 2$. Then $x_0 \in \partial K$ but $\operatorname{int}(K) = (0,1)$ is isolated from $x_0$!
So, let's modify the question:
Question Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x_0 \in \partial(\operatorname{int}(K))$. Must there exist $\delta > 0$ such that for all $\delta' < \delta$, $B_{\delta'}(x_0) \cap \operatorname{int}(K)$ is connected?

The answer is no. Let $K = \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{n > 0} [\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n}]$. Then $\operatorname{int}(K) = \bigcup_{n > 0} (\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n})$, and we have that $0 \in \partial \operatorname{int}(K)$ because $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n}\right) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. On the other hand, for any $\delta > 0$, the ball $B_{\delta}(0)$ contains infinitely many intervals $(\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n})$.

Thank you so much for your counter example. This helps.
